# Crystal - Make a bar chart span pages

Tags: crystal-reports, report, bar-chart

[Using Crystal reports 2008]

I have a horizontal bar chart in a report footer. This bar chart can possibly have more rows than can be viewed on one page. At the moment they all get squashed into one page and most of the labels along the y-axis are skipped.

How can I configure this bar char to span pages?
I would also like to be able to set the default width of each riser bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To control the size of the riser bars, go to the Chart Expert -> Options tab -> set bar size.